# Renaming a custom field name in User profile

Tags: user-profile

We have few custom fields in User profile. All users are set with data for those custom fields. I am trying to rename a custom field name in User Profile (Core DB) which results in that field value becoming empty. Again if we revert back the field name to old name then value is showing back. Please suggest.

Comment: Do you have custom code which references the fields by name? If so, you will need to change the names to the new names you are using

Comment: Yes. We are referencing and I have  updated code to point to new field name. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User profile fields are not `Sitecore.Data.Field`. What you define in the custom profile is merely a mapping so that Sitecore can provide a basic UI for the user, such as this.

[image]

Behind the scenes, these profile fields are used with the standard ASP.NET ProfileProvider - and this uses the profile name as key. Which means you cannot rename these, and expect to keep their value.

```
user.Profile.SetCustomProperty("Address", address);
user.Profile.SetCustomProperty("Phone", phone);
```

Explained here: [Sitecore users custom profile properties](https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2014/06/12/sitecore-users-custom-profile-properties/)

Answer (score 3):

Additional notes for Mark Cassidy's answer that, if you change the name of the user profile field in Sitecore you can migrate these values for the changed name.

So you need something like this:

```
foreach (var user in UserManager.GetUsers())
{
    var oldvalue = user.Profile.GetCustomProperty("Old Fields Name");
    user.Profile.SetCustomProperty("New Fields Name", oldvalue);
    user.Profile.Save();
}
```

Be careful because this `UserManager.GetUsers()` gets all users, and maybe you want to filter by domain for instance. Then you can use the `Domain.GetDomain("yourdomain").GetUsers()` method.